# Loading a sidebar on an Ajax call

Tags: filters, ajax, sidebar

I wanted to load a custom sidebar when doing an Ajax call, so I found the way with:

```
add_filter( 'loop_start', 'my_sidebar_widget', 25 );
```

but it is showing the sidebar even in media admin panel, so I thought about doing:

```
if( !is_admin() ) {
    add_filter( 'loop_start', 'my_sidebar_widget', 25 );
}
```

but it was still loaded in the media admin panel, so I tried:

```
add_filter( 'loop_start', 'my_sidebar_widget', 25 );

if( is_admin() ) {
    remove_filter( 'loop_start', 'my_sidebar_widget', 25 );
}
```

but in this way, the sidebar is not loaded on the Ajax call. Any idea of how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`is_admin()` returns `true` if you're doing an Ajax request. So this is why my code didn't work. Instead I've done this:

```
add_filter( 'loop_start', 'my_sidebar_widget', 25 );

function my_sidebar_widget() {
    if ( is_active_sidebar( 'my_sidebar' ) && (defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) || !is_admin() ) { 
        echo '<div id="my_sidebar">';
        dynamic_sidebar('my_sidebar');
        echo '</div>';

    }
}
```

`defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX` returns true if you're doing an Ajax call, and `!is_admin` will work if you're not doing an Ajax request. In this way, it is not shown in the Media Admin Panel.